# Vaadin 7.1.8 Uncaught client side exception

Tags: exception, client-side, vaadin

after migration from Vaadin 7.0.3 to Vaadin 7.1.8, Vaadin client side produce Exception when mouseenter/mouseleave event over Chrome plugin (NPAPI plugin).

creation plugin object code:

```
        Label pluginContainer = new Label("<OBJECT ID=\"chromePluginObj\" NAME=\"chromePluginObj\" WIDTH=\"100%\" HEIGHT=\"100%\" type=\"application/x-umekcc\"></OBJECT>", ContentMode.HTML);
        pluginContainer.setWidth("100%");
        pluginContainer.setHeight("1115px");
        pluginContainer.setStyleName("htmlLabel");

        addComponent(pluginContainer);
```

screenshot of app:

[image: normal state]

when trigger mouseenter/mouseleave on plugin object:

[image: exception state]

also when i open window (vaadin window) or make other UI changes, vaadin ?recreate? my object, and browser send NPP_Destroy event to NPAPI plugin, and its destroy:

[image: plugin destroyed]

Maybe there is a possibility to specify Vaadin not recreate my NPAPI plugin object?

also apologize for my bad English))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem can be caused by a corrupted widgetset. Flush your webapp's `VAADIN` directory, then recompile the widgetset. If this doesn't help: recompile the widgetset without the `pretty` option instead of `obfuscate` to get more information about where in the JavaScript code the clientside exception occurrs.

Comment: Did you recompile with the 'pretty' option? What's the stacktrace?

Comment: yep, i try all 3 modes before ask this question

Comment: @blubb, can you tell me how you do this, please?

Comment: @Pere unfortunately not, we had a build task for this and I no longer work on that project...